# Prevent application routes from blocking plugin routes in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, ruby-on-rails-plugins

It appears that as of Rails 3 plugin routes are [now loaded after application routes](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/2592-plugin-routes-override-application-routes), which means that my default route blocks plugins such as [admin_data](https://github.com/neerajdotname/admin_data).

Currently I avoid this problem by using the following ugly hack in `routes.rb`, which works for plugins with their routes defined in `config/routes.rb`:

```
# Load plugin routes
$LOAD_PATH.each do |path|
  path = File.dirname(path)
  file = File.join path, 'config', 'routes.rb'
  if File.exists? file
    require file[0..-4]
  end
end

# Default root
match ':a', :to => 'foo#bar'
```

What is the proper way of setting my default route to a lower priority than that of plugins?

Comment: that looks to me like a unintended bug in rails. I don't know of any other solution than your hack. perhaps log a bug report in lighthouse?

Answer (score 0):

I believe engines rather than plugins are the preferred way of adding app-esque functionality like this in Rails 3. You could try out the more modern engines-based [rails_admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) instead of admin_data if that's the only plugin you're using like this